# Creating a transparent PNG using an FBO creates an empty image

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm making a Minecraft mod where i'm trying to render all the icons of blocks to a transparent PNG-image. This is my first time using OpenGL and I just can't find the issue I'm having: the output is just a transparent PNG-image with nothing in it.

Note that Minecraft also works with a framebuffer.

In the start, this part of the code creates the framebuffer, depthbuffer and texture.

```
        // Clear some buffers
        glClearColor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Create and bind framebuffer
        int fbo = glGenFramebuffersEXT();
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);

        // Create and bind depthbuffer
        int drb = glGenRenderbuffersEXT();
        glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, drb);
        glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, size, size);
        glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, drb);

        // Create and bind texture
        int tex = glGenTextures();
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        // Specify a texture image
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA8, size, size, 0,GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, (ByteBuffer)null);

        // Bind texture to framebuffer
        glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);
```

This part renders the block or item...
(Note that this part renders fine when rendering in the Minecraft Framebuffer)

```
        // Render a Minecraft block or item
        // Commented out code is used for lighting and size
        glLoadIdentity();
        glEnable(GL12.GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);
        //RenderHelper.enableGUIStandardItemLighting();
        //glScalef(10F, 10F, 10F);
        itemRenderer.renderItemIntoGUI(mc.fontRenderer, mc.getTextureManager(), is, 0, 0);
        //glScalef(0.1F, 0.1F, 0.1F);
        //RenderHelper.disableStandardItemLighting();
        glDisable(GL12.GL_RESCALE_NORMAL);

        /* Draw a rectangle - Testing purposes
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f(0, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(1, 0, 0);
        glVertex3f(0, 1, 0);
        glEnd();
        */

        // Unbind framebuffer
        glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
```

And finally an image is created using the previously created texture...
This last part is a heavily edited version of the Minecraft ScreenshotHelper class.

```
        // Based on the minecraft screenshot-helper
        int k = size * size;

        if (pixelBuffer == null || pixelBuffer.capacity() < k)
        {
            pixelBuffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(k);
            pixelValues = new int[k];
        }

        glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        pixelBuffer.clear();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL12.GL_BGRA, GL12.GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV, pixelBuffer);

        pixelBuffer.get(pixelValues);
        TextureUtil.func_147953_a(pixelValues, size, size);
        BufferedImage bufferedimage = null;

        bufferedimage = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < size; ++i1)
        {
            for (int j1 = 0; j1 < size; ++j1)
            {
                bufferedimage.setRGB(j1, i1, pixelValues[i1 * size + j1]);
            }
        }

        // Create directory and finally the png file
        File file = new File(mc.mcDataDir, "renders");
        file.mkdir();
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bufferedimage, "png", new File(file, GameData.itemRegistry.getNameForObject(is.getItem()).replace(":", "_").concat(".png")));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The image is created fine, but there's nothing in it! It's just a transparent 500x500 PNG-image.

**Edit 1**
Using the `glGetError` function, I've found out that after binding the fbo it returns `GL_INVALID_ENUM` and `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT` returns 0.

**Edit 2**
Apparently after using `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT`, `glGetError` always returns this error.

**Edit 3**
Silly me, I put the wrong enum in `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT`. Now I'm getting `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT` back from it.

**Edit 4**
Updated the code. Still not getting any image. I've also included some testing code for drawing a triangle instead. This also doesn't render anything. Code is now also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/JonaBrackenwood/IconRenderMod).

Can somebody point out what I did wrong?

Comment: Are you attaching the texture to the framebuffer (with `glFramebufferTexture2D`)?

Comment: @GuyRT Thanks for noticing! I've added it to the question and my own code and tested it again, just to be sure. Still with the same result though.

Comment: Are you certain that you've loaded the identity matrix? Have you tried drawing the framebuffer on the screen to make sure it's not the modified screenshot-taker that's the problem? Maybe drawing a colored solid quad to the framebuffer as a debug test? As well, what item are you drawing? A block, a regular 2d-sprite item, or a piece of Forge voodoo that uses a custom 3d model?

Comment: @SDLeffler I've tried loading the identity matrix and it's still the same. Also, I'm rendering are all items as they are visualized in an inventory using the same renderItemIntoGUI function Minecraft uses.

Comment: Have you read through the item render function itself? Are you sure it doesn't bind the Minecraft FBO when you're not looking?

Comment: @SDLeffler Yes, the only thing this function does is work with depth, alpha and lighting while rendering quads for the models using textures or an icon. There's no mention of a FBO anywhere in it or the referenced functions.

Comment: Have you isolated which line that the GL_INVALID_ENUM error comes from? GL_INVALID_ENUM indicates that you have used an incorrect OpenGL integer enumerator at some point in your program (like calling glBegin(GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT), which obviously should throw a tantrum if called like that.) There can be some very insidious instances since some OpenGL enums are very similar to other, very different enums.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the information! I put the wrong enum in `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT`, hence the error. Updated the information in the post again to correct this. Meanwhile a friend tried drawing a triangle using my code on a Mac and it draws some glitchy textures. When using the same code I only get a black background.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're clearing the framebuffer - you need to clear it with `glClearColor(0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F); glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` which will clear the color buffer and the depth buffer, hopefully clearing the depth buffer to the Minecraft standard depth using the Minecraft standard depth test. Also, you can use `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;` to get rid of the GL11. part from your function calls and enumerators, and I believe you can also do `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.EXTFramebufferObject.*` to do the same for EXTFramebufferObject.

Comment: Not clearing the depth buffer could lead to the lack of anything being drawn in the FBO, but I doubt this is the case.

Comment: I've now updated the code to reflect these changes. Still nothing being drawn after clearing the framebuffer. If anyone wants to check it out, the code is now also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/JonaBrackenwood/IconRenderMod)

Comment: Looking over your code, I don't think you give the chance for a rendering cycle to take place before dumping to the png. I mean you are creating, binding and taking back the texture in the same for loop, but you never give the chance for the rendering pipeline process to actually go to the point where a swap buffer occurrs.

Comment: @MichaelCMS And if I put the code in the one second loop, where the other code draws an item on Minecraft's framebuffer, would that work?

Comment: What you should try to do, is create a texture only once (not on every frame), then try to take the texture's graphics after the 1st rendered frame . Since it's a color texture attachment , it will get rendered into once the pipeline finishes all the fragments drawing.

Comment: What now appears to be happening is that you're clearing your FBO for every item you render, and you're rendering your items in the same place every time. You want to bind your FBO, clear it ONCE, and then render.

Comment: @MichaelCMS This sounds like some kind of buffering. I'm not really sure how to do this and I'm also not sure it would really help.

Comment: @SDLeffler I'm not really sure how to clear a framebuffer. When clearing the color and depth buffers only once or when only creating and binding the framebuffer once, I'm still getting empty images.

Comment: @Jona Think of it this way. 1st loop you say to your engine that you are attaching a texture to your render buffer. At the end of the loop the engine actually renders into that texture. At the 2nd loop the texture is already rendered into (so not empty anymore), and you get the information from the texture and use it forward. Search PostProcessing effects and how they are done (such as Blur, Bloom etc) . It's the same principle : render into a texture , after glDraw you can use the texture with the new data inside.